# how to disable the highlighting view on selection either in html or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I have implemented onclick ,mapping and ahref functionality in my **PHONE GAP** project.While using this functionality either for onclick or mapping or ahref --while selecting the image or text it gets highlighted.

I don't want it get highlighted.I tried implementing this following code

```
noSelect
{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

But,this code made no difference in the SELECTING VIEW.

So,please suggest me a way to handle this and solve my problem.

**EDIT:**

This is how i have used it in mapping and image but it isn't working.

**mapping**

```
<div id="main" class="main" ><img src="img/abc.png" alt="abc" usemap="#abc" class="noSelects"/></div>
```

**image source**

```
document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = '<img src="img/image1.png" onclick="detail()" class="noSelect"/> '
```

Comment: i think you missed a dot before noSelect

Comment: @Sowmya please check the edit cersion of the question

Comment: @AntonioSalvati,nope i did add it while executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this in your css will work:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

---

have a look here, maybe it's helpful

http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/essential-phonegap-css-webkit-tap-highlight-color.html

Comment: anyway it's important for a mobile user to know if a button has been clicked or not..

Answer (score 1):

This may help you **:**

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo of what you have tried, so that we can work on it...?